# Get list of stored procedures which Inserts without column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to obtain a list of all the stored procedures which are inserting into a table without specifying the column names.

The closest I get by using the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckSQLModules]
AS
    DECLARE m CURSOR FOR
         SELECT '[' + s.name + ']'  + '.[' + o.name + ']' AS name, o.type_desc
         FROM sys.sql_modules m
         INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
         WHERE m.is_schema_bound = 0

    DECLARE @name sysname, @type_desc sysname

    OPEN m

    FETCH NEXT FROM m into @name, @type_desc

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC SP_REFRESHSQLMODULE @name
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
                ROLLBACK
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
            PRINT  @type_desc + ': ' +  @name
            PRINT ''
        END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM m INTO @name,  @type_desc
    END

    CLOSE m
    DEALLOCATE m
GO
```

But I am not sure whether the result coming is 100% correct .

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when asking a question like this it's best to include a little detail about what you've tried thus far. Anyhow, this should get you started.

```
SELECT      
  ObjectName = obj.Nm,
  Preview    = SUBSTRING(def.Txt, srch.Idx, 100)+'...',
  FullDef    = SUBSTRING(def.Txt, 1, 100)
FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES                     AS r
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(r.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA+'.'+r.SPECIFIC_NAME)) AS obj(Nm)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(obj.Nm))))  AS def(Txt)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('INSERT ',def.Txt)))          AS srch(Idx)
WHERE       r.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
AND         srch.Idx > 0;
```

Which returns (truncated for brevity):

```
ObjectName                           Preview                             FullDef
------------------------------------ ----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
metadata.usp_objectReadmeSections    INSERT metadata.objectReadmeSe...   CREATE PROC metadata.usp_objec...
dbo.usp_BuildCalendarAB              INSERT dbo.CalendarAB SELECT d...   CREATE PROC dbo.usp_BuildCalen...
metadata.usp_diskUsageByDB           INSERT ##dbSizeInfo...              CREATE PROC metadata.usp_diskU...
```

This returns the details for any stored proc that includes an INSERT statement. I'm not making a distinction here by what kind of table you are inserting into (temp, table variable or regular table.) You can, however add additional filters as needed.

Comment: I have tried this , It is listing all the Sps which have insert query but i need only those where it is inserting without specifying the column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the code using regular expression to see, if there are patterns like

> INSERT TABLENAME SELECT
>   INSERT TABLENAME VALUES

As TSQL does not support regular expressions, You can either write a CLR stored procedure or run this against your local code base.

Below is a sample regular expression to check for these kinds of cases. You have to enable ignoring cases and also using extended regular expression.

```
INSERT\s+[a-zA-Z0-9$_]+\s+(SELECT|VALUES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing T-SQL without a script DOM is not trivial because of the many variants of semantically identical language constructs. Trying to do so with string searching is fragile at best as it will be difficult to determine whether text is in executable code, comments, split among multiple lines, etc.

Consider using the [`Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom) assembly available in the [official Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86/). This assembly can be used programmatically in .NET for ad-hoc needs, such as your code analysis rules. Below is a PowerShell example that parses all stored procedures in the specified database, listing those that have `INSERT` statements without an explicit column list.

```
# add script dom assembly type, downloading if needed
Function Add-TSqlScriptDomType() {

    $dacFxNuGetUrl = "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64"
    $scriptDomAssemblyPath = "$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"

    if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($scriptDomAssemblyPath)) {
        # assembly doesn't exist in this script folder, download latest DacFx package from NuGet and extract the T-SQL Script DOM assembly here
        #download DacFx NuGet package containing assembly
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dacFxNuGetUrl
        if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
            throw "Unable to download Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom NuGet package: $($response.StatusCode) : $($response.StatusDescription)"
        }

        # decompress NuGet package to temp folder
        $tempZipFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() + ".zip")
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($tempZipFilePath, $response.Content)
        $response.BaseResponse.Dispose()
        $tempUnzipFolderPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
        Expand-Archive -Path $tempZipFilePath -DestinationPath $tempUnzipFolderPath
        $tempZipFilePath | Remove-Item

        # copy Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll assembly and remove temp files
        Copy-Item "$tempUnzipFolderPath\lib\net*\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll" $scriptDomAssemblyPath
        $tempUnzipFolderPath | Remove-Item -Recurse
    }

    Add-Type -Path $scriptDomAssemblyPath

}

# return count of insert statements in script without explict column list
Function Get-InsertStatementCountWithoutColumnList($script) {

    $insertStatementCountWithoutColumnList = 0

    # use the appropriate TSqlParser version for the target SQL Server version
    $parser = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSql140Parser($true)
    $parseErrors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ParseError]
    $scriptReader = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($script)
    $fragment = $parser.Parse($scriptReader, [ref]$parseErrors)
    $scriptChanged = $false
    if($parseErrors.Count -eq 0) {
        foreach($statement in $fragment.Batches[0].Statements[0].StatementList.Statements) {
            switch($statement.GetType().ToString())
            {
                "Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.InsertStatement" {
                    # $statement.InsertSpecification.Columns
                    if($statement.InsertSpecification.Columns.Count -eq 0)
                    {
                        $insertStatementCountWithoutColumnList += 1
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        throw "Error(s) parsing script"
    }
    return $insertStatementCountWithoutColumnList

}

############
### main ###
############
try {

    Add-TSqlScriptDomType

    $connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString);
    $query = @"
SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(p.name) AS procedure_name, sm.definition
FROM sys.procedures AS p
JOIN sys.sql_modules AS sm ON sm.object_id = p.object_id;
"@
    $selectCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
    $connection.Open();
    $reader = $selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
    while($reader.Read()) {
         $insertStatementCountWithoutColumnList = Get-InsertStatementCountWithoutColumnList -script "$($reader["definition"])"
        if($insertStatementCountWithoutColumnList -gt 0) {
            Write-Host "Procedure $($reader["procedure_name"]) has $insertStatementCountWithoutColumnList insert statements without a column list"
        }
    }

}
catch {
    throw
}
```

Note that this example downloads the NuGet package and extracts the assembly into the current script folder and uses that location for the `Add-Type` reference. You could instead use a NuGet package manager if you configure the NuGet repo.

Answer (score 0):

Following Alan Burstein's suggestion, I managed to reach this solution:

- Create a function called replacespace to better filtering procedure text.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReplaceSpace(@txt varchar(MAX)) RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
   RETURN replace(replace(replace(replace(@txt, char(13), ''), char(10), ''), char(9), ''), ' ', '') 
END
GO DROP TABLE IF EXISTS # t 
GO 
DECLARE @tb_name varchar(100) = 'table_name', @len int 
SELECT
   @len = len(@tb_name) 
   SELECT
      @len = @len + 1 
      SELECT DISTINCT
         object_id INTO # t 
      FROM
         sys.procedures 
      WHERE
         object_definition(object_id) like '%' + @tb_name + '%' CREATE nonclustered INDEX # t_i1 
         ON # t(object_id) 
         DELETE
            # t 
         WHERE
            object_id not in
            (
               SELECT DISTINCT
                  t2.[object_id] ProcedureName 
               FROM
                  sys.sql_dependencies t1 
                  INNER JOIN
                     sys.procedures t2 
                     ON t1.object_id = t2.object_id 
                  INNER JOIN
                     sys.objects t3 
                     ON t1.referenced_major_id = t3.object_id 
               WHERE
                  t3.[name] = @tb_name
            )
            SELECT
               ObjectName = obj.Nm,
               Preview = SUBSTRING(def.Txt, srch.Idx, 100) + '...',
               Preview2 = dbo.ReplaceSpace(replace(replace(replace(SUBSTRING(def.Txt, srch.Idx, 100), 'insert', ''), 'into', ''), 'dbo.', '')),
               Preview3 = substring(dbo.ReplaceSpace(replace(replace(replace(SUBSTRING(def.Txt, srch.Idx, 100), 'insert', ''), 'into', ''), 'dbo.', '')), @len, 1),
               FullDef = SUBSTRING(def.Txt, 1, 100) 
            FROM
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES AS r CROSS APPLY ( 
            VALUES
               (
                  r.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA + '.' + r.SPECIFIC_NAME
               )
) AS obj(Nm) CROSS APPLY ( 
            VALUES
               (
                  OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(obj.Nm))
               )
) AS def(Txt) CROSS APPLY ( 
            VALUES
               (
                  CHARINDEX('INSERT ', def.Txt)
               )
) AS srch(Idx) 
            WHERE
               r.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' 
               AND dbo.ReplaceSpace(replace(replace(replace(SUBSTRING(def.Txt, srch.Idx, 100), 'insert', ''), 'into', ''), 'dbo.', '')) like @tb_name + '%' 
               AND srch.Idx > 0 
               AND object_id(obj.nm) in 
               (
                  SELECT
                     object_id 
                  FROM
                     # t
               )
               AND substring(dbo.ReplaceSpace(replace(replace(replace(SUBSTRING(def.Txt, srch.Idx, 100), 'insert', ''), 'into', ''), 'dbo.', '')), 16, 1) <> '('
```